# Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{2x^{2x+1}+ax+b}{x^{2n+2}+4x^{2n+1}+5}$ if $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, find $a$, $b$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\displaystyle f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{2x^{2x+1}+ax+b}{x^{2n+2}+4x^{2n+1}+5}$ if $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, find $a$, $b$

My attempt:
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{2x(x^{2n})+ax+b}{x^2(x^{2n})+4x(x^{2n})+5}\\
f(x)&=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{2}{x+4}&;|x|>1\\
\dfrac{2+a+b}{10}&;x=1\\
\dfrac{ax+b}{5}&;1>|x|>0\\
\dfrac{b}{5}&;x=0
\end{cases} 
\end{align}
Are there any theorems that will help solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac2{x+4}&\text{ if }|x|>1\\\frac{ax+b}5&\text{ if }|x|<1\\\frac{2+a+b}{10}&\text{ if }x=1\\\frac{-2-a+b}2&\text{ if }x=-1.\end{cases}$$In order that $f$ is continuous at $1$, you must have$$\frac25=\frac{2+a+b}{10}=\frac{a+b}5.$$Therefore, $a+b=2$. And, in order that $f$ is continuous at $1$, you must have$$\frac23=\frac{-2-a+b}2=\frac{-a+b}5.$$Therefore, $-a+b=\frac{10}3$. So $a=b=\cdots$